# Automatically assigning attribute to line features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a network of railway switches and I need to assign the value of a switch line being left or right automatically.

What do I have:
A feature class containing a track that looks like this

[image]

I need to generate something that looks like the following.

[image]

The red arrow is always the direction you look at the intersection and that helps you determine if the lines branching out are left or right.

Can I achieve this in ArcGIS or using ArcPy and, if so, which library to use for coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it AND implemented it (in parts).

**Solution: Vertex Cross Product**

Say, if a line passes through the origin, and has a point P in it's vicinity, the vector cross product can be calculated to determine if the point is on the left, right or on the line.

[image]

So, the vector cross product (Bx * Py1)-(By * Px1) will be positive if the point is on the left side of the line and negative if it is on the right side of the line.

Using this concept, I calculated the vector cross product for the endpoints of the fork and determined if the point is to the left of one of the fork lines, the fork itself is a right fork and viceversa.

**Implementation: A bit of ModelBuilder and ArcPy**

Pre-processing - ModelBuilder 
1. I got a layer with points at the forks.

[image]

2. I created a one meter buffer around those points and obtained the fork lines that intersected with the buffer. This also helped me group the fork lines.
3. I got the start and end vertex of all the three lines.
4. Since I know the coordinates of the point at the fork, I made some processing such that all three lines have the coordinates of the fork point as startpoint and the endpoint as the line end point (calculated from line start-end geometry)
5. I re-positioned the forks such that the origin is (0,0). For this, I subtracted the line start and end coordinated by the start coordinate.

[image]

Processing - ArcPy

6. I read the objectID, fid of the buffer, end coordinates in a list of tuples and did some Python coding to loop through the records to find the vector cross product.
7. I looped through the code such that the vector cross product is calculated only for the ends of lines with the least distance.
8. Finally I got a list of tuples containing the [(ObjectID, Buffer_FID, coordinates,  Switch_Side)]
9. I updated the feature class with a the values of the switch side using UpdateCursor and it works! :D

Of course, I want to pool all my efforts in a single python toolbox. This is just simple railway switches. Things will complicate with double switches, double slips etc. but hey it's a start! I thought I would post the answer for somebody else who might need some inspiration.

Answer (score 5):

It is a long process but doable without programming:

- dissolve your lines (no multiparts)
- derive end points and delete overlapping
- spatially join end points (1:m) and count number of lines connected to node:
  [image]
- buffer ones with count of 3 and intersect with original lines
- dissolve intersect to multipart lines using buffer fid
- derive ends of multipart lines and remove ones that intersect original nodes
- convert points to line (close line) using relevant field to form a line:
  [image]
- create polygons from closed lines. This is a key, because polygons are made of clockwise points (!)
- assign unique ID to each polygon and split it at vertices
- compute their length, sort ascending by length and remove duplicates of polygon ID.

Start of remaining segment intersect left leg at fork, end of it sits on right leg:

[image]

Comment: Hi @FelixIP, Thank you for your answer. The thing is some of the tools you mention are available only in advanced package and I don't have it. Despite circumventing many things, I still don't get the last part. I create polygon from lines and split the polygon at vertices to get lines again? If the polygon  is created clockwise, how would the tool know which is the starting point?

Comment: When you split it, result are 3 lines. The shortest is 1 of interest, thus sort and delete identical.

Comment: Tools you mention are easy to replicate in arcpy. Invest in it.

Answer (score 1):

The Python math library.  If all your lines are pointing towards the branch and each line is composed of only a start and end node you could get the angle in radians from the source line coordinates, select the two lines that intersect the end node, calculate those radians.  If the radians are lower than the source line it branches right otherwise it branches left.

Here is some ham-fisted code to get you started...cursors and selections not shown.

```
def CartetesianToPolar(xy1, xy2):
    import math
    'Given coordinate pairs as two lists or tuples, return the polar coordinates with theta in radians'
    x1 = xy1[0] * 1.0
    y1 = xy1[1] * 1.0
    x2 = xy2[0] * 1.0
    y2 = xy2[1] * 1.0
    xdistance = x2 - x1
    ydistance = y2 - y1
    distance = math.pow(((math.pow((x2 - x1),2)) + (math.pow((y2 - y1),2))),.5)

    if xdistance == 0 and ydistance > 0:
        theta = math.pi/2
    elif xdistance == 0 and ydistance <0:
        theta = 3*math.pi/2
    elif ydistance == 0 and xdistance > 0:
        theta = 0
    elif ydistance == 0 and xdistance < 0:
        theta = math.pi  
    else:
        theta = math.atan(ydistance/xdistance)
    return [distance, theta]
```

Comment: Hello GBG, Thank you very much for your input! It works splendidly in the ideal scenario where the switches are geometrically oriented in such a way that they are on either side of the x-axis. However, when they are both pointing upwards (if you know what I mean), the slope of the lines both give a positive angle w.r.t to the x-axis and it is difficult to differentiate then :| It is definitely a start. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @April - You are confusing a Cartesian coordinate system with a polar coordinate system.  The only got-yous to my answer would be if the source line was facing eastward or northeasterly but the right branch faced southeasterly.  In this case the thetas from both branches would be greater than the source line...or the the source line faced southeasterly but the left branch faced northeasterly, then both branches would have thetas less than the source line.  You could check for this in your code and make adjustments.

Comment: I am not really sure what "sourceline" you keep mentioning. I assume it is the line that leads to the fork point?

Comment: @ GBG - I assumed that by getting the angle of the line, I can ascertain which coordinate it falls in but apparently that is not so. Kindly let me know if my assumptions are right - 1. xy1 and xy2 are lists of x y coordinates of line segment. Calculating the 'theta' of the line gives the orientation of the line w.r.t to x-axis. So, i thought I can ascertain the quadrant. But, now you mention I am confusing it to a cartesian coordinate system. So, how do I interpret the angle calculated in polar coordinates as specified in the code?

Comment: @ GBG - Also, my coordinates are calculated in a cartesian system. The reference frame is a PCS i.e. SWEREF 99. I checked everywhere but the calculation for the angle of the line is tan inverse of (y/x). Ah! If only I can ascertain the quadrant the line falls in, I can ascertain the left and right :|